# What is behaviour and PIE.htc in a CSS file I am looking at on the web?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am looking at some CSS and I see the following:

```
#header-nav>ul>li ul li:last-child {
-moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
behavior:url(PIE.htc);
}
```

I don't know anything about this. What's behavior and what is PIE.htc.  I have never seen these before.

Comment: have you even *tried* to find the answer on google? You can start here: http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi as per your question about behavior and PIE.htc

Actually we use this behavior property to define the path of PIE.htc (JS file) for IE when we need a css curved squares with the support of IE so this **PIE.htc** support the border radius property in IE   as i mentioning sample css code :-

```
.addFav {
border: 5px solid blue;
width: 200px;
height:200px;
background:red;
padding:20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

Here is the live example :- http://jsfiddle.net/8LFLd/6/

or read more about PIE.htc (http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The `behavior` property is for Internet Explorer version 5+. `behavior`lets you attach a script using CSS in order to implement DHTML (Dynamic HTML) components.
It's only supportet by IE and no other browsers.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/behavior

You can use it to fix things for IE that are not supportet by default, for example transparent PNG files in (very) old IE versions:
http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530723(VS.85).aspx